# How to retrieve the same model from another REST url in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The models tree of my emberJS app match the tree of my API however, I have 2 different routes returning the same type of data :

`/products/` and `/users/:id/supported_products/` both return products data.

When I need to have the `products` of the app there is no problem :

```
 this.store.query('product',params);
```

However I am not sure how to query products from the user path. The place to do so would be the adapter, but I need to define a secondary adapter that I would call when I need supported products,and I have no idea how to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if it were me I would create a *virtual* query parameter that would instruct a custom adapter on how to change the endpoint on the fly.

For example I might have a `supportedByUser` flag. Then in my `app/adapters/product.js` do something like this:

```
import JSONAPIAdapter from 'ember-data/adapters/json-api';
export default JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  urlForQuery(query, modelName) {
    let userId = query.supportedByUser;
    delete query.supportedByUser;
    return userId
      ? `${this.namespace || ''}/users/${userId}/supported_products`
      : this._super(...arguments);
  }
});
```

Here is an example twiddle demoing this: https://ember-twiddle.com/b406391e98ed4fda30bc227a894fa7c9